# Huawei Push Kit Notification Message key/value is null in Android

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I have implemented Huawei Push Kit to my application.
Data messages have been processed by implementing **HmsMessageService**.

The notification message delivered to the device very well, but when you tap the notification, **key/value** value that you actually entered is displayed as null. I have set name of the**intent filter**  **exactly same** with the string on the Console. At the bottom, payload and value are displayed as null even though I filled it from the console. What might be the problem?

In addition, the value was fetched via getIntent from onCreate where the activity started. However, **getIntent()** is not null.

[image: Console]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the phone you are using for receiving the push messages are not meeting with the minimum data message requirements.

[image: push restriction]

Here is a official link about restrictions : [Documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/restrictions-0000001050040064-V5)